# Trying to create a macro which checks for a macro variable existence and creates it if doesn't exist

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
%Macro symexistchk(valuex);
                %if %symexist(&valuex) %then %put &valuex;
                    %else %do; %let valuex = 0;
                            %end;
%Mend symexistchk;

%symexistchk(g900_r);
```

I want to check if macro variable g900_r exist and create one if it doesn't exist.

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it... There were 2 key things you were missing.  You need to include the %global statement to declare the macro as a global macro variable.  This will make it available outside of the macro.  You also were missing the `&` in your %let statement where you assign it to zero.

Your final code should be something like this:

```
%Macro symexistchk(valuex);

  %if %symexist(&valuex) %then %do;
    %put Macro Variable &valuex exists.;
  %end;
  %else %do; 
    %global &valuex;
    %let &valuex = 0;  * NOTE THE AMPERSAND TO THE LEFT OF THE EQUALS SIGN;
    %put Macro Variable &valuex created and initialized to zero.;
  %end;
%Mend symexistchk;

%symexistchk(g900_r);
%put &g900_r;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to assign the newly created macro to the global scope with `%global`, resolve your macro variable argument in the `%let` statement (so you are not just creating a variable called valuex) and [evaluate the resolved macro variable](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001071915.htm) in your `%put` statement with `&&&`.

```
%macro symexistchk(valuex);
    %if %symexist(&valuex.) %then %put Already exists: &valuex = &&&valuex;
    %else %do;
        /* Make macro variable available outside macro */
        %global &valuex.;
        %let &valuex. = 0;
        %put Assigning: &valuex = &&&valuex;
    %end;
%mend symexistchk;
%symexistchk(mVar);
%symexistchk(mVar);
```